# SQL Server: Use output from first insert to insert into second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, output, sql-insert

I have a basic stored procedure that adds a new record to a table with a structure like the following. The table also has a column "itemID" that is set to auto-incrementing to create a unique id for each record.

I would like to use Output to get this id from the new record I inserted and then use this to add a new record to another table (**Table2 with columns colD, colE, colF**). colF in Table2 should be the Output from the below as this is the id that links both tables.

Can someone here tell me how this would work as I am pretty new to SQL and have never done this before ?

**My stored procedure (example):**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateStuff]
    @colA datetime,
    @colB varchar(50),
    @colC nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO Table1
        (
            colA,
            colB,
            colC
        )
    SELECT  @colA,
            @colB,
            @colC
END
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: no i think output clause is ideal scenario.just google it for syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    /* Here declare a Table Variable */

    DECLARE @Table_Var TABLE(itemID INT)

    INSERT INTO Table1(colA,colB,colC)
    OUTPUT inserted.itemID INTO @Table_Var(itemID)
    SELECT @colA,@colB,@colC
    
    
    /* Now do the insert into Table 2*/        
    INSERT INTO TABLE2
    SELECT itemID FROM @Table_Var
END
```

`SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is only good when you are doing a single Insert, and it is an IDENTITY column whos value you want to capture. It will only return the last Generated Identity value.

Other then that if you are doing multiple insert or it isn't an identity column then you should use `OUTPUT` clause along with a table variable/temp table to capture the inserted values. and then do whatever you want to do with them values later on (insert in another table/logging whatever).

To learn more about [`OUTPUT Clause`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) have a look at this link.

Comment: Where would I declare the other input for Table2 ? If I declare them together with the ones for Table1 above AS BEGIN than I get an error that the number of SELECT and INSERT values does not match.

Comment: Have a look now I have chnaged the name to table variable to @Table_Var , this is the table you will declare before the very 1st insert then you will use the OUTPUT cluase in your INSERT statement to populate this table variable. Now when yor insert into Table2 (the table you have mentioned in your question), you will INSERT into table2 selecting values from the table variable.

Comment: colD, colE, colF whereas colF is the one that contains the id (output) from Table1.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateStuff]
    @colA datetime,
    @colB varchar(50),
    @colC nvarchar(20),
    @Valueout int output
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO Table1
        (
            colA,
            colB,
            colC
        )
    SELECT  @colA,
            @colB,
            @colC
SET @Valueout = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - this looks interesting ! Can I do the insert into Table2 in the same procedure ?

Comment: @user2571510 You can indeed

Comment: And how ? Just adding it below ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Trigger on the table as follows:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_Name 
       ON  Table_Name 
       AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
    AS 
    BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;

       INSERT INTO Table1 ( colA, colB, colC )
       SELECT  colA, colB, colC FROM Inserted

    END
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. What is Inserted in that case ?

Comment: Inserted is a Keyword of SQL server what points the Table_name where you inserted.